# Converting COUNTIFS to SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, countif

I am making a interactive spreadsheet in which I dumped a bunch of data in one worksheet and then doing some quick analysis on another worksheet.  From there I am making a Chart based on the analysis worksheet data.    I was using this:

```
=COUNTIF('RFC Data'!G:G,"Work in Progress")
```

to pull data into the analysis worksheet and it worked great.

I had a tricky one where I used:

```
=COUNTIFS('RFC Data'!J:J,"4 - Low",'RFC Data'!T:T,"No",'RFC Data'!U:U,"No users affected")
```

where I had 3 criteria.

The issue is when I filter data worksheet it is not updating the analysis worksheet and in turn not the Chart.

So I updated the analysis worksheet to use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('RFC Data'!G:G,ROW('RFC Data'!G:G)-MIN(ROW('RFC Data'!G:G)),,1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Work In Progress",'RFC Data'!G:G))+0)
```

which works great.  The issue is I am having a bugger of a time to update the tricky one with `=SUMPRODUCT`.

I tried a few dozen things but no luck!  Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using ISNUMBER(SEARCH here? That would be equivalent to using a search criterion with wildcards (asterisks) within COUNTIF. Not that it's wrong, but you're asking Excel to do more work than is necessary.

Comment: I will give that a shot!  Tyvm!

Comment: Updating first comment seeing I did not answer it...  I have used that before and it seems to work... I will go back and "tune" it once it is completely working...

Comment: So have you tried simply adding further clauses similar to the one you have in the SUMPRODUCT equivalent to your additional COUNTIFS criteria?

Comment: Perhaps I am going about this wrong.  The original issue is when I filter data worksheet it is not updating the analysis worksheet and in turn not the Chart.  Is there a way to overcome this?  In the past, I have had spreadsheets that did this, but for some reason it is not for this one...

Comment: I could try to use COUNTIFS but they do not appear to work with the filtering when I use it...

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say update your SUMPRODUCT/SUBTOTAL set-up.

Comment: I was able to make some headway.  =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(CalcRisk,ROW(CalcRisk)-MIN(ROW(CalcRisk)),,1))*((CalcRisk="4 - Low")*(ServiceDisruption="No")*(UsersAffected="No users affected")*(Type=”Minor”))) works but when I try to pull back an additional item, I am getting 0.  =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(CalcRisk,ROW(CalcRisk)-MIN(ROW(CalcRisk)),,1))*((CalcRisk="4 - Low")*(ServiceDisruption="No")*(UsersAffected="No users affected")*(Type=”Minor”)*(**"Type=”Significant”**)))  See how I am trying to count the two items from Type. It is not working - I am getting 0

Comment: You mean the entry in the Type column could be EITHER "Minor” OR ”Significant”?

Comment: I actually want the count of the total both.  There are six different Types in total.  Is that possible?  I tried a bunch of different things but no luck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A given entry in that column can't simultaneously be "Significant" and "Minor". What was wrong with the logic in my previous statement that you didn't understood (or perhaps misunderstood), which I repeat: you want a count which  
for which the entry in the Type column could be EITHER "Minor” OR ”Significant”?

Comment: Either, yes... Sorry...

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(CalcRisk,ROW(CalcRisk)-MIN(ROW(CalcRisk)),,1)),0+(CalcRisk="4 - Low"),0+(ServiceDisruption="No"),0+(UsersAffected="No users affected"),0+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Type,{"Minor","Significant"},0)))

Comment: For some reason it does not like this portion of it - 0+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Types,{"Minor","Significant"},0))‌​  .... Note, I changed the name of one table from Type to Types for obvious reasons...  I will keep playing with it...

Comment: I only copied the names from the formula you posted earlier!